# Installing applications in Kali not there when I reboot?

Tags: kali-linux

I've tried to install an app successfully but every time I log out and reboot (off USB) the application is not there anymore. It's like it never installed. Each installation the app does install and work until I shutdown and reboot - It's gone..Poof!!

Answer (score 6):

Since you’re new to all this, you should spend a little more time reading the [Kali documentation](https://docs.kali.org/). This points out two things:

- [Kali isn’t appropriate for new Linux users](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux):

  > Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is **NOT** a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.
- [Kali Live forgets everything on shutdown](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence) and needs specific setup to remember changes (including applications you install). Ideally, if you want to run Kali with non-default packages from a USB stick, you should [build your own Kali image](https://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso) and use that.

(As pointed out by [SDsolar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/197427/sdsolar), you should bear in mind that USB might be compromised if you use your USB key on random computers; a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM would be safer.)

Comment: Upvote.  It isn't all that difficult to use as a primary system, which will remember everything you do.  But the whole point I am gathering from the OP is the idea of having a portable version to do testing from random computers.  Apps can be installed for use by the USB stick but if it is set up the way I think it is, all those apps would need  to be present before it is written to the USB drive.  I would choose to burn it all to a custom LiveCD instead of a USB.  You never know for sure that your USB is always read-only.  If that random PC has a gotcha in it the USB could get infected.

Comment: Having said all that, I'm afraid the real problem is your first point.  It is not geared towards people who are just learning Linux.  I'd recommend Ubuntu for that.  Or pick up a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks @SDsolar, I’ve added the gist of that to my answer.